# Change PayPal recent activity from 7 days to 30 days

Tags: paypal

In my PayPal account dashboard, at the bottom of the page, I have a table that displays my recent activity from the last 7 days.

[image: screen shot]

Is it possible to change from last 7 days to last 30 days?

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED but:

> The History page will show you the last 30 days transactions.

[To view all of your transactions, click History near the top of the page.](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/article/?solutionId=FAQ2334)